# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __gdbm_lock_file error with GDBM gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, homebrew, dyld, gdbm

I'm getting this odd error when I try to use the [Ruby GDBM gem](https://github.com/presidentbeef/ffi-gdbm).  The gem used to work.  Now when I invoke it I get this error (across many different versions of ruby):

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __gdbm_lock_file
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libgdbm.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: __gdbm_lock_file
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libgdbm.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

I've tried numerous ruby versions, executing directly from Rbenv and even installing/uninstalling my brew GDBM installation.  My GDBM Brew installation is at `/usr/local/Cellar/gdbm/1.12`  GDBM works when I invoke it manually from the command line (e.g. `gdbm_load`).

The only thing I can think has changed is that I'm now running on OSX El Capitan 10.11.6.  Or that I somehow made a change to my config or PATH files that could have caused this error.

How can I go about resolving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GDBM ruby gem's maintainer [has confirmed it's an issue with either HomeBrew or GDBM itself.](https://github.com/presidentbeef/ffi-gdbm/issues/5)

Manually installing GDBM without using HomeBrew, or installing it with:

`brew install gdbm --build-from-source`

can fix the problem.